# Use 2 different lightning:recordViewForm inside one SLDS Page Header

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, lightning-recordviewform

I want to show data from 2 different objects inside an [SLDS Page Header](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/page-headers/)

For the page header I use `<ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">`

For the data - I use [lightning:recordViewForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/specification)

If I get data from one object - all looks and works well :

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1IW0000001CGSbMAO" objectApiName="Budget__c">
    <ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
        </li>
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

[image]

When I want to get data from 2 different objects, I tried many different things and could not find a way to show it OK:

**First try**

I tried to put the `<ul>` element outside the `lightning:recordViewForm`, and then all the css gets messed up:

```
<ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1IW0000001CGSbMAO" objectApiName="Budget__c">
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
        </li>
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        </li>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1HW0000002vh5xMAA" objectApiName="Payment__c">
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
        </li>
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        </li>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</ul>
```

[image]

**Second try**

I tried to put 2 `<ul>` elements and it looks nice but it creates 2 lines:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1IW0000001CGSbMAO" objectApiName="Budget__c">
    <ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
        </li>
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1HW0000002vh5xMAA" objectApiName="Payment__c">
    <ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
        </li>
        <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

[image]

**Third try**

I have tried to put these 2 `<ul>` in `slds-grid` so it would display in one line but it does not space up the fields:

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1IW0000001CGSbMAO" objectApiName="Budget__c">
            <ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
                </li>
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                </li>
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Description__c" />
                </li>
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Version__c" />
                </li>
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="LastModifiedById" />
                </li>
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="CreatedById" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </lightning:recordViewForm>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a1HW0000002vh5xMAA" objectApiName="Payment__c">
            <ul class="slds-page-header__detail-row">
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" />
                </li>
                <li class="slds-page-header__detail-block">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </lightning:recordViewForm>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I have tried to play around a lot with the chrome dev tool so it will align nicely but couldn't find any solution that would be OK

Is there any solution to display more than one lightning:recordViewForm object inside SLDS Page Header?

Comment: I dotn really see any attempt to set a size on your rows for each 'form' to occupy within the header, for example, using a grid, but also leveraging `slds-col slds-size_1-of-2` or using lightning:layout's with  layout:item size attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is use a grid:

```
<lightning:layout>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
    ...
  </lightning:layoutItem>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
    ...
  </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

Note: if the fields are different sizes, the fields may not line up, but they will be side by side.

Comment: Thanks, it is better than what I have tried, but still does not behave well, especially when the screen gets smaller

Comment: @ItaiShmida you may need to use smallDeviceSize/mediumDeviceSize to eventually squeeze into a one-column-per-line mode instead. It's not reasonable to fit two columns on a phone's portrait mode. Check out lightning:layoutItem for the various options.

Comment: OK, but I do not want 2 columns - I want to display a list of fields in 1 row

Comment: There's no SLDS for this design, so you'll probably have to try and figure out your own, probably involving force:recordData and rendering your own page header.